# Using NamedPipes causes issues with Antivirus

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes, antivirus

I am seeing a strange issue with my application, it uses NamedPipes for IPC communication.  The only file that ever gets transferred over it is an serialized to xml object. I have not seen the issues locally on my pc, as I guess my antivirus is not scanning them, but I have a few customers who are seeing issues where they get timeout messages and pipe failures. If they disable the antivirus realtime scanner it works just fine. What made us suspect the antivirus is a customer was complaining that since they installed our application their antivirus (NOD32) has crashed non stop. We disabled the application from running, crashing stops, turned it on yesterday and today crashing starts back up.

Has anyone had issues with this in the past? I'm wondering if moving to WCF would prevent this, I was just hoping that I would not have to do namespace reservations. I liked the NamedPipes because they worked great for transmitting information between processes.

TIA

Comment: Have you tried contacting ESET for help on this?

Comment: It sounds like you need to do localized test before we can help you.  Once you discover what block of your code causes the problem we can help you determine a workaround.  **Until you do a localized test we cannot help.**

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with antivirus programs (not just NOD32) about 5 years ago. What worked for me was to string-base64 the transferred messages. I hope that this trick will work for you too.

Comment: Base 64, kept my app from crashing, NOD32 still crashes, seems to be an issue with ESET that I can't fix. My next fix will be to test to see if Authenticode signing the application and dll will work.